# Outlook item Unicode

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I'm trying to read email by subject works great if you use English language only

If the subject has any special character cant read it , I am using multi languages! it can be Swedish or German i `System.Text.Encoding.Default`  but didn't really worked for me any tips

```
For Each row As DataRow In Email_Subjects.Rows
                If InStr(LCase(SubFolderObject.Items(i).Subject), LCase(row("Email Subject"))) > 0 Then             
                    If UnRead Then
                        If SubFolderObject.Items(i).UnRead Then
                            table.Rows.Add(SubFolderObject.Items(i).ConversationID, SubFolderObject.Items(i).EntryID, SubFolderObject.Items(i).CreationTime, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Subject, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Body, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Attachments.Count)
                            SubFolderObject.Items(i).UnRead = False
                        End If
                    Else
                        table.Rows.Add(SubFolderObject.Items(i).ConversationID, SubFolderObject.Items(i).EntryID, SubFolderObject.Items(i).CreationTime, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Subject, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Body, SubFolderObject.Items(i).Attachments.Count)
                    End If
                End If      
            Next row
**Thanks in advance **
```

Comment: [MailItem.InternetCodepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.InternetCodepage). Anyway, you should get all text Unicode (UTF-16LE) encoded.

Comment: Thanks Jimi 
I'm using a data table rows, how I convert the current row item to compare 'InStr' with the email subject? 
I need to covert the subject as well 
Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Now I saw your answer :D "Anyway, you should get all text Unicode (UTF-16LE) encoded"
Can you drop an example ?

Comment: An example about what? The first thing you have to do is to drop any VB6/VBA method and use VB.Net instead (if you're actually writing VB.Net code). Strings in .Net are all Unicode encoded. You never mentioned what your DataTable is and where it's coming from. You mentioned `Encoding.Default`, but you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: You are right im mixing VBA and VB.net,

Comment: If you have any example with VB.net kindly lead me :)

Comment: VBA is fully Unicode enabled. Does it work if you get rid of LCase? Can you give of a value and a subject that do not work?example

Comment: Also, you should never loop through all items in a folder - use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.